# Eigen small size Tensors disastarous performance

Tags: c++, performance-testing, eigen3

I have a question to Eigen's unsupported tensor module, see [1](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/), [2](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support), [3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Working_notes_-_Tensor_module) and [4](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html). I like to use it for small size tensor, e.g. second and fourth order tensors with 3 dimensions. I wrote a performance test using [google's benchmark module](https://github.com/google/benchmark). And Eigen performes really bad in my oppinion.

Here is the code I used.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <array>

// eigen double contraction benchmark
void BM_eigen(benchmark::State& state)
{
    Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<3,3>> A;
    A.setConstant(1.0);
    Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<3,3,3,3>> B;
    B.setConstant(2.0);
    Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<3,3>> C;
    C.setConstant(0.0);

    static const Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 2> contraction_pair
        { Eigen::IndexPair<int>(2, 0), Eigen::IndexPair<int>(3, 1) };

    while (state.KeepRunning())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); ++i)
        {
            C = B.contract(A, contraction_pair);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(A);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(B);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(C);
        }
    }
    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations() * state.range(0) * sizeof(nullptr));
}

// raw loops for double contraction benchmark
void BM_loops(benchmark::State& state)
{
    std::array<double, 9> A;
    A.fill(1.0);
    std::array<double, 81> B;
    B.fill(2.0);
    std::array<double, 9> C;
    C.fill(0.0);

    while (state.KeepRunning())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); ++i)
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
                for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    C[i + j * 3] = 0.0;
                    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                        for (std::size_t l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                            // C[i * 3 + j] += B[i * 27 + 9 * j + 3 * k + l] * A[k * 3 + l];
                            C[i + j * 3] += B[i + 3 * j + 9 * k + 27 * l] * A[k + l * 3];
                }

            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(A);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(B);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(C);
        }
    }
    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations() * state.range(0) * sizeof(nullptr));
}

BENCHMARK(BM_loops)->Arg(1);
BENCHMARK(BM_loops)->Arg(8);
BENCHMARK(BM_loops)->Arg(64);
BENCHMARK(BM_loops)->Arg(512);
BENCHMARK(BM_loops)->Arg(1024);

BENCHMARK(BM_eigen)->Arg(1);
BENCHMARK(BM_eigen)->Arg(8);
BENCHMARK(BM_eigen)->Arg(64);
BENCHMARK(BM_eigen)->Arg(512);
BENCHMARK(BM_eigen)->Arg(1024);

BENCHMARK_MAIN()
```

And I compiled it ones using

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -O3 -std=c++14 -I /usr/local/include/eigen3/ benchmark.cpp -lbenchmark -lpthread -o benchmark
```

And if I run the code I get the following output

```
$ ./benchmark 
Run on (4 X 3300 MHz CPU s)
2017-11-04 17:38:52
***WARNING*** CPU scaling is enabled, the benchmark real time measurements may be noisy and will incur extra overhead.
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time           CPU Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
BM_loops/1            47 ns         47 ns   15196904   161.447M items/s
BM_loops/8           376 ns        376 ns    1961059    162.12M items/s
BM_loops/64         3666 ns       3664 ns     251142   133.257M items/s
BM_loops/512       27198 ns      27196 ns      25595   143.635M items/s
BM_loops/1024      54874 ns      54834 ns      12663   142.475M items/s
BM_eigen/1           490 ns        490 ns    1218410   15.5745M items/s
BM_eigen/8          4697 ns       4693 ns     173951   13.0047M items/s
BM_eigen/64        32712 ns      32711 ns      22122   14.9273M items/s
BM_eigen/512      241772 ns     241599 ns       2822   16.1684M items/s
BM_eigen/1024     501559 ns     501541 ns       1455    15.577M items/s
```

This means using Eigen slows down my code by a factor of approximately 10. Am I wrong, or are Eigen tensor's really that bad for small sizes?

Best regards,

Jonas

Comment: You can either calculate the value of `i + j * 3` and place into a constant temporary variable before the `for (k` loop or use a pointer to `C[i + j * 3]`, since it doesn't change in the `k` or `l` loops.

Comment: Try using temporary constant variables for expressions involving `i` and `j`.  They can be calculated and assigned before the `k` loop, since they don't involve `k` or `l`.

Comment: If `state.range(0)` doesn't change in the loops, assign it to a constant temporary variable before the `i` loop.

Comment: You may be able to speed up your program by changing how you access your arrays.  You want all the arrays to fit into the processor's cache, or reduce the number of times that the processor needs to reload its cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Thomas Matthews. But my question was why Eigen performs much worser than a naive Loop without your optimizations. I'm aware of better solutions for the Implementation using loops.

Comment: shouldn't you pass A to B.contract() ( instead of C )? that alone could explain the slow down depending on how eigen.tensor deals with aliasing ...

Comment: Your so right. But i think it still performes much worser. But i will fix this an update my question! Thanks alot!

Comment: another problem is that you're not initializing A,B in either cases; technically, you're invoking undefined behavior; practically, the compiler may apply further spurious optimizations as a consequence...

Comment: I adapted the code. So the tensors are initialized and also std::arrays are used. Now the factor is 10 but this is still horrible I think...

Comment: I see; to have a more fair comparison, you shoud compute the contraction from a contraction_pair object in the loop case; alternatively, are you sure eigen.tensor does not offer a contraction() method with compile-time-known contraction_pair ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes, thanks for your suggestions. But sadly there is no compile time contraction. That's really sad. I really enjoy using Eigen's API...

Comment: ok, an easy thing you could try is to move the expression construction outside the benchmark loop, that is, auto expr=B.contract(... outside the loop and C=expr; inside... ( in this way, index setup should not get included into timing as it should be)

Comment: and one more thing, I don't use eigen.tensor so I don't know, but you should also make sure that vectorization is on at eigen side ( are there macro/compiler switches ? I do use eigen, and I do know that some optimizations are not always automatically activated on older compilers ... )

Comment: Thanks for the answers and excuse my late response. If I take the epxression construction outside the loop it speeds up a little bit, but no appreciable speedup. As I'm aware of eigen automatically vectorizes the code as written [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization). Which optimizations can I optimize in your opinion?